# BizTalk with BTARN: Cannot locate document specification because multiple schemas matched the message type "string"

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2013, mscorlib

We have an installation of BizTalk 2013 which also has the BizTalk Accelerator for RosettaNet (BTARN) installed.  There is an orchestration which we consume as a WCF service (generated using the BizTalk WCF Service Wizard).  The orchestration is compiled against .NET v4.5 as is the code which calls the orchestration through WCF.  The incoming message type for the orchestration is a schema we've defined (also compiled against v4.5) which contains a bunch of strings. Here's a snippit of the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://zzz.Engine.Schemas.RequestCanonical" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://zzz.Engine.Schemas.RequestCanonical" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Request">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:properties>
          <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='Request' and namespace-uri()='http://zzz.Engine.Schemas.RequestCanonical']/*[local-name()='Document' and namespace-uri()='']" />
          <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='Request' and namespace-uri()='http://zzz.Engine.Schemas.RequestCanonical']/*[local-name()='SenderId' and namespace-uri()='']" />
        </b:properties>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Document" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SenderId" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Since we've installed the BTARN component into BizTalk we're unable to successfully call the orchestration through WCF.  This error occurs:

```
Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.XmlAsmException: C0C01306: Cannot locate document specification because multiple schemas matched the message type "string".
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.XmlAsmStreamWrapper.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InitStreamInput(Uri baseUri, String baseUriStr, Stream stream, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteCount, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitStream()
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(Stream input, Uri baseUri, String baseUriString, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkBodyWriter.WriteBizTalkBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initial
```

This is understandable since the BTARN component has installed `mscorlib v2.0.0.0` into the `BizTalk.System` resources and our Application installs `mscorlib v4.0.0.0` when deployed.

The presence of both of these libraries confuses BizTalk and it can't decide which to use to resolve the type `string`.

I've attempted to resolve this by marking all the references to `System` in our schema, pipeline, and orchestration DLLs to `Use Specific Version` but this has no effect.

How might I resolve this issue?

**Update:**

These are entries listed under `All Artifacts -> Schemas` which have the Root Name `string`:

[image: listing of schemas with root name string]

As you can see the only duplicate namespaces here are the two entries which have a blank namespace.  Could this be the cause of the conflict?  Before installing BTARN the third entry (`mscorlib v2.0.0.0`) was not present.

I have attempted to define a custom `string` data type so `mscorlib` is not referenced here but I haven't been able to do that successfully so far.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have schemas schemas deployed with the Root node name of string (not with elements of type string) in the same namespace.  If you can't change that (it seems in this case you might not be able to?), change the send ports involving these messages to use the `PassThruTransmit` pipeline rather than the `XMLTransmit`.  That way, it won't try to do schema resolution on that message type.

---

For BizTalk to resolve a schema to a document, it relies on the root node name and namespace forming a unique key - this is the BTS.MessageType property.  In the screen shot below, taken from an environment I'm working in now, you can see I have three schemas deployed (I got this view by going to the `All Artifacts->Schemas` node in the admin console, sorting it by node name, and going to where I could see string as the root node name):

[image: Schemas]

The first column in the picture gives you the assembly name - you can see that two are from the GlobalPropertiesSchemas that is stock to BizTalk, and one is from a custom assembly from one of my applications (the far right column here shows the application - by default there's another column I took out for readability).

These schemas would have the following MessageTypes:

- `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding#string`
- `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/#string`
- `http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/#string`

So when a pipeline goes to get the document spec by message type, it won't get any duplicate key violations.  However, if the namespace was the same for any two of them, it would cause problems when trying to send messages of that message type (the error you're getting now).  You need to look through your deployed schemas and find out what assemblies/applications have **duplicate MessageTypes with Root Name string**.  Chances are, the RosettaNet accelerator installed a schema you are also deploying in your application.  The solution there would be to remove it from your application and reference the RosettaNet schemas library in your application instead.

Comment: I updated my post to show the entries with the `Root Name` of `string`

Comment: It seems strange to me that mscorlib has been imported into the BizTalk database (as opposed to just being referenced from the GAC) - I can't say I've seen that before.  It also seems strange that BizTalk is treating the string datatype as a schema.

Comment: If you can't resolve that, just change the ports that send this schema to PassThruTransmit, and then it won't try to do schema resolution.